# Does Amazon EC2 integrate into Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

My question is that I wanted to launch a Windows Amazon EC2 server that could through UNC connect to Amazon S3.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Cloudberry Drive will map a local/network drive to your server/desktop and S3 will be reachable via an UNC path.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, but only through third party applications. For example [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/). I think [Cloudberry lab's S3 explorer](http://cloudberrylab.com/default.aspx?page=cloudberry-explorer-amazon-s3) can do that as well (not sure if it's the free version or the PRO version).

Comment: I didn't think about that +1

Comment: can you create a tag for cloudberry?

Comment: @Antoine Seems a silly thing to make a tag for. Ask on meta if you think it's a good idea: http://meta.serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.

Access to S3 is accomplished via http calls, using either Amazon's SOAP or REST interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

No, Amazon S3 is for web applications to store data via GET and POST calls like user data. There is no way to use it as tradition storage for windows as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools to allow you to mount s3 as a local drive, these work just as well from EC2

Comment: James, do you know the name of these tools?